# How to define graphql query in schema with exactly one of two parameters required

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-relay

I have a graphQL ApolloServer returning a paginated set of Transaction(s) for an Account. Here is a snippet of my schema:

```
type Account implements Node {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}
type Transaction implements Node {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  accountId: ID!
}
```

The relay spec https://relay.dev/graphql/connections.htm says the field that returns a connection type can take parameters of either:
1)  `before` and `last`
or 
2)  `after` and `first`

This implies they cannot all be optional without defining a default `after` or `before` opertation

For a query that handles only the `after` case, I would make a required after thus:

```
type Query {
  accounts: [Account]!
  transactions(accountId: ID!,after: String!, first: Int = 10 ): TransactionsBelongToAccountConnection
}
```

But for one that handles both the `before` and `after` case, I would need to make all four of these parameters optional and declare one of `after` or `before` modes to be the default:

```
type Query {
  accounts: [Account]!
  transactions(accountId: ID!, before: Sting, last: Int = 10, after: String, first: Int = 10 ): TransactionsBelongToAccountConnection
}
```

or (my question is) in graphql is there a way of making exactly one of two parameters required?

Comment: There is no built-in way of doing that. Your arguments need to be nullable and the logic for requiring one or the other needs to be placed inside your resolver.

Comment: Thanks Daniel Rearden, this is a duplicate question. I was searching in a context specific to react relay connection, should have just thought of it as a graphql issue.